# Python: Find closest matches on a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, pattern-matching, tuples

I have a list of the following form:

`[("AAPL", "Apple Inc."), ("TSLA", "Tesla Inc."), ("BB", "BlackBerry Limited")]`

I want to find the closest match when a user enters either a company name OR a symbol. For example:

`IN: "Apple I"
 Out: "AAPL"`

`IN:"BB"
 OUT:"BB"`

I tried using [difflib.get_close_matches](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) but I was having trouble figuring out a good way to keep the company name and ticker symbol together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> good way to keep the company name and ticker symbol together

We just need to make an intermediate mapping for it:

```
import difflib

data = [("AAPL", "Apple Inc."), ("TSLA", "Tesla Inc."), ("BB", "BlackBerry Limited")]
index = {name.lower(): symbol for symbol, name in data}
index.update({symbol.lower(): symbol for symbol, name in data})

def search_for_company(text):
    return set(
        index[name_or_symbol]
        for name_or_symbol in difflib.get_close_matches(text.lower(), index.keys())
    )

 print search_for_company('Apple I')  # set(['AAPL'])
 print search_for_company('BB')  # set(['BB'])
 print search_for_company('aapl')  # set(['AAPL'])
```

Comment: Entering ``aapl`` yields an empty list

Comment: @APorter1031 Thanks a lot, I changed my code drastically